# 3 variables multiplication with 1 constraint lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

The question states that : Suppose we want to optimise the function $f(x,y,z) = ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2$, where $a$, $b$, $c$ are positive constants, subject to the constraints $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 1$ and $x,y,z > 0$. Show that this problem has only one solution and the optimal value of $f(x,y,z)$ is equal to $(a^3 + b^3 + c^3)^{\frac 13}$.

My teacher just teaches us how to solve this type of problem with degree 1, but not of degree 2 and 3, so I have no idea how to solve this question.
Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please edit your post adding what you did while trying to solve the problem. And, while your at it, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Solve the system
$$2ax+3\lambda x^2=0$$
$$2by+3\lambda y^2=0$$
$$2cz+3\lambda z^2=0$$
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Lagrange function with Lagrange multiplier $ \lambda: $ $$ \mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda)=f(x,y,z)-\lambda(x^3+y^3+z^3-1) $$
satisfying the following equations:
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x}=2ax-3\lambda x^2&=0\\
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial y}=2by-3\lambda y^2&=0\\
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial z}=2cz-3\lambda z^2&=0\\
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial \lambda}=-(x^3+y^3+z^3-1)&=0
\end{cases}
Since $ a,b,c,x,y,z>0 $, we have $ \lambda\ne 0 $ and
\begin{cases}
x=\dfrac{2a}{3\lambda}\\
y=\dfrac{2b}{3\lambda}\\
z=\dfrac{2c}{3\lambda}\\
x^3+y^3+z^3=1
\end{cases}
So you have
\begin{align}
27\lambda^3=8(a^3+b^3+c^3)
\end{align}
i.e., $$ 3\lambda=2\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3+c^3} $$
and
\begin{cases}
x=a(a^3+b^3+c^3)^{-\frac{1}{3}}\\
y=b(a^3+b^3+c^3)^{-\frac{1}{3}}\\
z=c(a^3+b^3+c^3)^{-\frac{1}{3}}
\end{cases}

So the minimum value of $ f(x,y,z) $ constrained to the conditions is 
$$ f(a(a^3+b^3+c^3)^{-\frac{1}{3}},b(a^3+b^3+c^3)^{-\frac{1}{3}},c(a^3+b^3+c^3)^{-\frac{1}{3}}) $$ which is $$ (a^3+b^3+c^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}. $$

Comment: thank you so much. Your response is so clear and makes me understand how to solve the problem.

Comment: @戴穎煒 You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Calling

$$
L(x,y,z,\lambda) = ax^2+b y^2+z z^2-\lambda(x^3+y^3+z^3-1)
$$

the stationary conditions are

$$
\begin{cases}
2ax-3\lambda x^2= 0\\
2b y - 3\lambda y^2 = 0\\
2c z - 3\lambda z^2 = 0\\
x^3+y^3+z^3= 1
\end{cases}
$$

So we have

$$
\begin{cases}
x = \frac{2a}{3\lambda}\\
y = \frac{2b}{3\lambda}\\
z = \frac{2c}{3\lambda}\\
\left(\frac{2a}{3\lambda}\right)^3+\left(\frac{2b}{3\lambda}\right)^3+\left(\frac{2c}{3\lambda}\right)^3=1
\end{cases}
$$

or

$$
\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3+c^3} = \frac{3}{2}\lambda
$$

substituting back we have

$$
\frac{x^*}{a} = \frac{y^*}{b}=\frac{z^*}{c} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3+c^3}}
$$

and thus

$$
f(x^*,y^*,z^*) = \frac{(a^3+b^3+c^3)}{\left(a^3+b^3+c^3\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}  = \left(a^3+b^3+c^3\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}
$$